# Find the value of the complex integral

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Find the value of $K = \frac{i}{4-\pi} \int {\frac{1}{z\cos(z)}}\,dz$ over the circle centred at origin with radius 4.

Here the value of $I = \int{\frac{1}{z\cos(z)}}\,dz = 2\pi i(\text{Res}_{z=0} + \text{Res}_{z=z_n})(f(z))$, where $z_n = (2n+1)\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Now, $z= 0$ is a removable singularity so at 0 residue will be 0.

At $z_n$ residue is $\frac{2}{{(-1)^{n+1}(2n+1)\pi}}$. So $I = -4i \tan^{-1}1 = -iπ$. So, K = $(\frac{\pi}{4}) -1$.

But the final answer is $2$. It will be of great help if someone could find the value of $K = \frac{i}{4-\pi} \int{\frac{1}{z\cos(z)}}\,dz$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't there one more pole inside the contour?  And where did $\tan^{-1}$ come from.  And at $0$ isn't the residue $1$?

Comment: The pole at z=0 is not a removable singularity.

Comment: True. I tried expanding  series secz/z  but I missed out first term. My mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three simple poles of the function $\frac1{z\cos(z)}$ that are inside the circle $|z|=4$.  They are at $z=0$ $z=\pi/2$ and $z= -\pi/2$.

The associated residues t $z=0$ $z=\pi/2$ and $z= -\pi/2$ are, respectively

$$\lim_{z\to 0}\left(z\,\,\frac1{z\cos(z)}\right)=1$$

$$\lim_{z\to \pi/2}\left((z-\pi/2)\,\,\frac1{z\cos(z)}\right)=-2/\pi$$

$$\lim_{z\to -\pi/2}\left((z+\pi/2)\,\,\frac1{z\cos(z)}\right)=-2/\pi$$

Hence we assert that

$$\frac{i}{4-\pi}\oint_{|z|=4}\frac{1}{z\cos(z)}\,dz=\left(\frac{i}{4-\pi}\right)\,(2\pi i) \left(1-4/\pi\right)=2$$

as expected!

Comment: Okay so it is not necessary to consider all the odd multiples of π/2 where cosz vanishes right ? Little confused of why that is so.

Comment: Only the poles enclosed by $|z|=4$ result in contributions to the integral.

Comment: And feel free to up vote answers that you found useful. ;-)

Comment: So is it that |z|=4, angle varying from 0 to 2π, we have those two poles. So we need not consider every rotation.  Is this idea correct?

Comment: For $|z|=4$, $0<|z|$.  For $|z|=4$, $\pi/2<|z|$.  But for $|z|=4$, $|z|<3\pi/2<5\pi/2, \dots$.  Only the poles inside the contour $|z|=4$ are implicated.

Answer (score 0):

The first residue is $1$.  For the other, *two*, at $\pm \pi/2$, we get $-2/\pi$.  So we get $2\pi i(i/(4-\pi)(1-4/π))=2$.

Comment: How does this add anything to my posted answer?